# Raise syntax error when specific regex is used in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, syntax-error

I'm wondering if it was possible to raise syntax error (or at least warning) in eclipse environment when a specific regex is find ? (Like for example, each time there is the world "dummy" in the code, an error is risen)

Thanks in advance !

Julien.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "no". At least, not without some non-trivial tinkering.